# rails 4 asset javascripts not included in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Am using rails 4.1 application, when i add any js files in the application.js the javascript is not included in my application.

```
application.js
//= require jquery.nested-fields
```

if i add the same javascript in my view file externally the js included in my application.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :nested_form_fields %>

config/initializers/assets.rb

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( nested_form_fields.js )
```

what is the problem in the assets?

Comment: The file is `config/initializers/assets.rb` not `config/init/assets.rb`. Do you see any error message in the error console?

Comment: no errors anywhere, i guess assets java scripts configuration some where missing, but totally no idea about this

Comment: Shouldn't it be `//= require nested_form_fields` instead of `//= require jquery.nested-fields`?

Comment: i see two different name files, in the application.js you should add the file name properly, so if the name is "nested_form_fields.js" you should write it like "//= require nested_form_fields", this is normally for vendor file, but if your adding file to the assets folder you only will need this into the application.js file "//= require_tree ."

Comment: not only `//= require jquery.nested-fields` , tried with `//= require nested_form_fields` , cocoon js `//= require cocoon` . when i add any js file in `application.js`  its not included, so i added the JavaScript tag in the view file then js file is added in the application.

Comment: have u tried `<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>` instead of  ` <%= javascript_include_tag :nested_form_fields %>`